# How to reverse-project 2D coordinates to a z=n plane in 3D

Tags: opengl, 3d, webgl

I want to "unproject" 2D coordinates back to 3D space, to a given `z` plane. (Where z is known, so are the projected 2D coorinates and the `pMatrix` and `mvMatrix` used).

Web search only shows up with `gluUnProject`'s variants which has a comletely different use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make sure that your screen-coordinates are in the right coordinate-space, that is between `-1` and `1`.

Then you need to combine projection and model-view matrices into a single one. Sample code using Javascript and [glMatrix](http://glmatrix.net/) for convenience:

```
var m = mat4.create();
mat4.multiply(m, pMatrix, mvMatrix);
```

On Wikipedia you can find the basic [formula used with projection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix#Perspective_projection). Factoring out those multiplications and solving them for `x` and `y` will give you (screenshot from mxMaxima):

[image: Perspective matrix solved for x and y]
*Note the column-major format in indexes.*

The JS version of this formula (with `x2` and `y2` being the projected 2d coordinates, `x` and `y` being the original 3d ones and original `z` was known):

```
var x=-((m[8]*(m[5]-m[6]*y2)+m[4]*(m[10]*y2-m[9])+(m[6]*m[9]-m[10]*m[5])*x2)*z+m[4]*(m[14]*y2-m[13])-m[12]*m[6]*y2+(m[13]*m[6]-m[14]*m[5])*x2+m[12]*m[5])/(m[4]*(m[2]*y2-m[1])-m[0]*m[6]*y2+(m[1]*m[6]-m[2]*m[5])*x2+m[0]*m[5]);
var y=((m[8]*(m[1]-m[2]*y2)+m[0]*m[10]*y2+(m[2]*m[9]-m[1]*m[10])*x2-m[0]*m[9])*z-m[12]*m[2]*y2+m[0]*m[14]*y2+(m[13]*m[2]-m[1]*m[14])*x2-m[0]*m[13]+m[1]*m[12])/(m[4]*(m[2]*y2-m[1])-m[0]*m[6]*y2+(m[1]*m[6]-m[2]*m[5])*x2+m[0]*m[5]);
```

As a bonus you can get the distance from the projection plane with:

```
var w = m[10]*z+m[6]*y+m[2]*x+m[14];
```

Comment: What coordinate system are the original 2D coords in to begin with? I am a bit surprised you are able to do this without knowing the viewport mapping, but that assumes you are starting with window-space coordinates.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman The 2D coords must be in the `-1 .. +1` space. You just have to divide the pixel (mouse) coordinates with the viewport's pixel width and height, so (0,0) is the center of the viewport and almost certainly negate the `y` value. - Everything else (information wise) is in your two matrices.